# Xcode source control view history modified files fail

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control

I used **Xcode** source control to connect with **SVN server**.

After check out the source, I executed the **commit**, **update**, all work fine.

But when I click **Source Control > History**, and click show modified files, then show an alert dialog:

> The source control operation failed,because no working copy could be found.
>
> Make sure the file is in a valid working copy and try again.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have the same problem.. Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: What was your XCode version? I'm facing same issue with XCode 7.0.1

Comment: I'm also using Xcode 7.0.1, and I didn't get any solution.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7.1.1, and I have the same problem.

Comment: It sounds like the original check out didn't create a copy correctly. How did you do the original check out, via Xcode or a command line clone?

Comment: @FiddleMeRagged I check out the code via Xcode source control.